Local Print Queue Redirect causes long delay
I am looking at options to provide Human friendly names for printers in a large corporate network that uses alphabet soup names for all printers across all branches.
The IT team is not receptive about changing names to ones that mere users would be able to understand where they are printing things.
I have been looking into options to support the local team and came across this question and answer - How can I provide a local alternate name for a printer in Windows 7
To summarise a local printer is setup that points at a port with the name \\<Server>\<PrinterName> with the local printer configured with the same driver as the print server.
I have been able to get this to work, and can set it up with a power-shell script that doesnt require admin, so it would be pretty easy to roll out.
The issue I would like to try and solve is that it appears to add a large delay of 2-3 minutes before printing starts as compared to just sending it direct to the shared printer.
Does anyone have tips on how this may be able to be resolved or investigated.

Would desktop shortcuts work? Simply make a shortcut to each printer and change its name. Copy the shortcuts (.lnk files) to other machines.

@DrMoishePippik How does one go about printing to a shortcut?
